# pgBench Fatal: need at least 2003 open files, but system limit is 1024

Tags: postgresql, pgbench

Am trying to run some testing using a connection pooler (pgBouncer). I am trying to run for 2000 clients via pgBench.

When running the following:

```
./pgbench -h 172.1.1.9 pgbench -p 6432 --client=2000 --progress=30 --time=120 --jobs=2 -C -U pgbench
```

I had set the pgBouncer file descriptor limit via the service itself however pgBench restricts me from running more than 1024. I have upgraded from 9.6 to 13 but still experiencing the issue.

How would I get round this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the bash shell, you would do `ulimit -S -n 2100` (assuming your system is configured to let you) to raise the limit.  For more details, read the docs for your shell.